# Openlayers text symbology is not being shown

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, symbology, sld

I have a Vector Layer in a .json file:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [ 
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Station_Id":107, "NAME":"ARDEBIL(F)","ELEVATION":"1314.3"}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 48.24 , 38.19 ] } }
    ]
}
```

For symbology I use an SLD, and the SLD File is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>me</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>GeoServer SLD Cook Book: Rotated square</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>salam Bar Mahdi 2</Name>
          <Title>Title 2</Title>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#00FFFF</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Stroke>
                 <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                 <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
                 <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1.0</CssParameter>
               </Stroke>
             </Mark>
             <Size>6</Size>
             <Rotation>0</Rotation>
           </Graphic>
         </PointSymbolizer>
         <TextSymbolizer>
           <Label>
             <ogc:PropertyName>NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
           </Label>
           <Font>
             <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
             <CssParameter name="font-size">120</CssParameter>
             <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
             <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
           </Font>
           <LabelPlacement>
             <PointPlacement>
               <AnchorPoint>
                 <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                 <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
               </AnchorPoint>
             </PointPlacement>
           </LabelPlacement>
           <Fill>
             <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
           </Fill>
         </TextSymbolizer>
       </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
   </UserStyle>
 </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I can see only a circle symbology and I can't see the text symbology.

Comment: 120 is **very** big - try 12, it's measured in Pts

Comment: I changed it, but same result.